# Hydra defaults using YAML: How to handle optional user configuration?

Tags: fb-hydra

I'm distributing an application which includes a several commands.

- Some commands require no user configuration as sane defaults can be packaged with the app
- Some commands require additional user configuration that must be provided by the user. This is configuration that is largely static and suitable for a configuration file

What I'd like to do is

1. Ensure the search_path contains both the user's homedir and the package where the default configuration is
2. Write the default configuration like

```yaml
# default_config.yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - .user-config

default1: value1
default2: value2
# ...
```

But this doesn't work - if `.user-config` isn't on a search_path Hydra errors with "Could not load '.user-config'."

The way I see to do this with Hydra is

1. Ensure the search_path contains both the user's homedir and the package where the default configuration is
2. Write the user configuration as

```yaml
# .user-config.yaml
defaults:
  - default_config
  - _self_

additional_config: foo
# ...
```

This makes the user configuration mandatory and also requires the `defaults:` stanza at the top.

Is there a configuration-based way of doing this or should I just load and merge the configuration in code?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try:

#### optional config in the defaults list

Using the [optional keyword](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/defaults_list) in your defaults list. Unfortunately this is only supported for configs in a config group.

```yaml
# default_config.yaml
defaults:
  - _self_
  - optional user: config

# see https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/search_path/
# Note that this is only supported in the primary config
hydra:
  searchpath:
    - file://${oc.env:HOME}/.my_app
```

A user can now place `~/my_app/user/config.yaml` in the search path.
`# @package _global_` will ensure that the config here overrides the global scope and not things under the config group node `user`.

```yaml
# ~/my_app/user/config.yaml
# @package _global_

additional_config: foo
```

(Avoid the temptation of adding your home directory directly to the search path, in some cases Hydra scans the search path and it will cause slowdown).

#### Generate a config dir from a template

You can do something similar to what [configen](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/tree/main/tools/configen) is doing. (IIRC it predated the ability to add the search path to the primary config, which can make things even better).

Basically, it has a Structured Config schema it's using as a default config.
It can generate a config dir for the user (with the initial config that contains the defaults list boilerplate).